# How can I batch or vbs the following CSV to remove certain characters?

Tags: regex, csv, batch-file

I'm setting up some files for output to a wood processing CNC and it requires that the out put from the CAD adheres to their format.

I've tried to do a Excel Macro on it but the operator finds it confusing to use it.

The CSV needs the ABS    1 to just be 1 and the CAM, filename to have the _1 and _2 removed (last 2 characters).

Appreciate it in advance! CSV as per attached code.

```
﻿"CAM, file name",Length ,Width,Thickness,Material,Count,Edge Left,Edge Right,Edge Top,Edge Bottom,Barcode,Grain
,800.00,418.00,1650.00,,1,,,,,,
DOOR_LH_13_1,395.50,778.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1",279162,
DOOR_RH_14_1,395.50,778.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1",279164,
bottom_front_5_1,764.00,100.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1",,,"ABS     1",279148,
top_4_1,764.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1",,"ABS     1","ABS     1",279146,
left_side_1_1,1650.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1",279140,
right_side_2_1,1650.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,"ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1","ABS     1",279142,
Divider_8_1,374.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279154,
Shelf_11_1,764.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279158,
Shelf_12_1,764.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279160,
Bottom_3_1,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279144,
shelf_6_1,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279150,
shelf_10_1,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,"ABS     1",,279156,
back_7_1,1632.00,764.00,18.00,white,1,,,,,279152,
```

Answer (score 0):

In batch you would process the csv usually with a `for /f` and
split at the comma, but `for /f` treats adjacent delimiters as only one.

So I suggest to use a script language with Regular Expressions like PowerShell.

```
(Get-Content .\SO_56900009.csv) -replace '"ABS *1"','1' -replace '(?<=_\d+)_\d'|Set-Content '.\New.csv'
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\New.csv
"CAM, file name",Length ,Width,Thickness,Material,Count,Edge Left,Edge Right,Edge Top,Edge Bottom,Barcode,Grain
,800.00,418.00,1650.00,,1,,,,,,
DOOR_LH_13,395.50,778.00,18.00,white,1,1,1,1,1,279162,
DOOR_RH_14,395.50,778.00,18.00,white,1,1,1,1,1,279164,
bottom_front_5,764.00,100.00,18.00,white,1,1,,,1,279148,
top_4,764.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,1,,1,1,279146,
left_side_1,1650.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,1,1,1,1,279140,
right_side_2,1650.00,400.00,18.00,white,1,1,1,1,1,279142,
Divider_8,374.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279154,
Shelf_11,764.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279158,
Shelf_12,764.00,352.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279160,
Bottom_3,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279144,
shelf_6,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279150,
shelf_10,764.00,382.00,18.00,white,1,,,1,,279156,
back_7,1632.00,764.00,18.00,white,1,,,,,279152,
```

To be on topic, you could wrap that one liner in a batch file:

```
powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content .\SO_56900009.csv) -replace '\"ABS *1\"','1' -replace '(?<=_\d+)_\d'|Set-Content '.\New.csv'"
```